# Ending simulation instantly C

Tags: c, codeblocks

To start off, I'm pretty new to the programming world. I have thorougly searched for an answer to my question, but the search engines never give me what I want.

I am programming in C, using Code::Blocks. I want to know if I could add a line of code that would end the running program immediately when that statement is encountered during the simulation. I want this to happen even if the statement is not in the main function.

For example, here is a very simple code with two functions (without the extra detail) to explain further. Keep in mind that this code is meant solely to explain my question and is not used for practical reasons.

```
int testc()
{
    for (c=0; c<=5; c++)
    {
        if (c == 2)
        {
        printf("Ending program");
        /*END RUN HERE*/
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
testc();
return 0;
}
```

I'm sorry if the answer is somewhere on the internet. I have been searching for the past hour and I can't seem to find a solution to my problem.

Comment: `exit()` from `stdlib.h`. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_exit.htm

Answer (score 5):

Yes, use the `exit( int )` function of `stdlib.h` where the parameter is the exit code of the process.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, note that `exit` is not quite instantaneous since it'll do some cleanup and run `atexit` handlers. `quick_exit` will do less cleanup but may still run some other handlers. While `abort` will exit right now, but potentially with a nasty error message.

Comment: Abort, abort, abort! :P